# Is there a way to automatically update windows 10 OS for computers in domain on group policy?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-policy

I want to be able to push a new group policy out with a powershell script (or scripts most likely) that will make all computers on our active domain update to the windows OS that we want. Currently there are hundreds of users and we don't have a way to update their computers other than doing it via remote desktop for each computer individually. But every computer has the .exe file required to update, just hasn't been run yet. Something like

```
wuauclt.exe /updatenow
```

I am also open to other suggestion on how to do this. I was thinking of sending all the users a batch file and having them run that and they could do it themselves. Any help would be appreciated and if this post wasn't specific enough I can answer questions or take it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never and I mean **NEVER** let user deploy updates on his/her computer themselves by clicking on some batch or exe file. Two reasons:

1. It will just not work and big part of machines will not be updated.
2. You are teaching users that they can run various and unknown batch files / powershell scripts / exe files, because it's safe.

Since you said "hundreds of users" I believe that you have some domain there.

What you might be looking for are the Group Policies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wufb-group-policy) or WSUS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-manage-updates-wsus).